# Pi camera to be activated when rf waves are detected

Tags: camera, raspicam, picamera, rfid

My cars have Fastags (RFID based cards) installed on the windshield. On the highway, on every toll booth there are rfid scanners that reads my card and deduct the payment. Since there is a possibility to misuse this tech, I'm thinking to add a camera module that can take pictures automatically when my fastags are scanned. I believe,  RPI can handle that job. So is there a module that can be added to rpi that can read the incoming rf waves and invoke my camera to take pictures???